# Access denied when mounting NFS

Tags: ubuntu, mount, nfs

I'm trying to mount a share with
root@client:~# mount -t nfs 192.168.0.109:/private /mnt/private

but get the following error
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 192.168.0.109:/private

I have the following in my exports and when I mount the public it works. 
/public *(ro,sync,no_subtree_check)
/private 192.168.0.110(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)

If I change the /private line to have a mask of /24 it works, 192.168.0.110/24.

Both my server and client are running Ubuntu 18.04 and have the firewall off.

Is there a reason it doesn't accept the IP without the mask. All the example I found online show you can specify the IP so not sure why this isn't working.

Comment: Wrong site, I'm afraid. You're looking for [ubuntu.se] instead. This site is for programming related questions, not general computer or OS support. You can find more information about this site in the [help]. Good luck.